# Powershell regex select portion of a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string that varies

```
BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB
```

The first part is what varies, it's basically a customer name. So the number of characters and spaces will change.

I know I can use this and it will match what I need

```
$String = 'BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB'
$string -match '(^\S+\s+\S+)(\s+)(CONTACT:)(\s+)(\S+)'
$Matches[1]
```

But if the string changes to something like this, with no spaces

```
CUSTOMERNAME            CONTACT:  MB
```

the -match is false.

How can I do a regex that grabs the first part of the string regardless of its length or characters?

Probably wasn't super clear. The Values I am after are

`$Matches[1]` - In the above would be BLUE ORIGIN

`$Matches[3]` - CONTACT:

`$Matches[5]` - MB

Comment: use `[A-Za-z\s]+CONTACT:\s+\S+`

Comment: Is there a tab (`\t`) between `ORIGIN` and `CONTACT` ?

Comment: Is the data before `CONTACT:` guaranteed to be fixed-length? If so, do you know what that length is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your regex work for both examples, you could change `(^\S+\s+\S+)` to `(^\S+\s*\S+)` making the whitespace `\s*` character match 0+ times instead of 1+ times.

```
(^\S+\s*\S+)(\s+)(CONTACT:)(\s+)(\S+)
.......^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4w89Z0/1)

You could omit the capturing group around `(\s+)` and just match `\s+` if you are not referring to it anymore in your tool or code.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression engines usually support partial matches of strings. Don't try to match all the stuff before `CONTACT:`

```
$s = 'BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB'
$s -match 'CONTACT:\s+(\S+)'
$Matches
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              MB
0                              CONTACT:  MB
```

(So you can just do `$Matches[1]` to get just the value you're after.)

If you need to break apart the whole line into several elements of data and not just this one, I don't think I'd use regular expressions. I'd look into developing a parser (syntactic analyzer). Doing that in PowerShell is probably ill-advised, though. [Here](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-csharp/#parserGenerators) are some .NET tools that might help with that.

Answer (score 2):

You are IMO overcomplicating things.
With placing the parentheses for the capture groups you decide what to capture.

```
$String = 'BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB'
$string -match '^(.*?)\s+(CONTACT:)\s+(\S+)' | Out-Null
$matches | ft -AutoSize

Name Value
---- -----
3    MB
2    CONTACT:
1    BLUE ORIGIN
0    BLUE ORIGIN             CONTACT:  MB
```

---

```
$string = "CUSTOMERNAME            CONTACT:  MB"
$string -match '^(.*?)\s*(CONTACT:)\s+(\S+)'|Out-Null
$matches | ft -AutoSize

Name Value
---- -----
3    MB
2    CONTACT:
1    CUSTOMERNAME
0    CUSTOMERNAME            CONTACT:  MB
```

Comment: Totally agree with just matching the strings you want to capture. This seems to best represent what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

**As per supplied data this will do job for you**

```
[A-Za-z\s]+CONTACT:\s+\S+
```

> Explanation

- `[A-Za-z\s]+` - Matches any alphabet or space one or more time.
- `CONTACT:` - Matches `CONTACT:`.
- `\s+` - Matches one or more space character.
- `\S+` - Matches one or more non space character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YCgz5B/1)